Triangulable versus trianguable
Triangulable and trianguable are both used in the sense of "can be triangulated" but it is not clear which one is correct.

triangulable
Capable of being triangulated
Wiktionary

What is the reason for this difference? Is one of them just a common misspelling? Are there different conventions in conflict here? Or is there even the slightest difference in meaning?

You say both words are used. Could you please cite a few examples where trianguable is used?

Perhaps most importantly, the ispell spell checker insists on trianguable instead of triangulable

A cursory internet search tells me that the former word is more often used. I'm sure you're more aware of this since you happen to be a user on MO and MSE. An Arxiv article I came across also uses triangulable. I think someone more familiar with topological stuff could weigh in on this.

Merriam-Webster has neither; the OED only has triangulable. I'd need better evidence than "a cursory internet search". If you're interested in topology, Stack Exchange has a wide range of mathematics boards frequented by actual mathematicians.

I would also include 'triangulatable' in the question.

The correct word is triangulable.
If you look at similar words, English verbs ending with late often turn into adjectives ending with lable.

Articulate → articulable,
Conciliate → conciliable,
Escalate → escalable,
Regulate → regulable,
Stimulate → stimulable.

This rule seems to hold only for longer words; if the words are short (one or two syllables), you add able after the at:

Debate → debatable,
Inflate → inflatable,
Relate → relatable,

So triangulable is formed from triangulate according to this general rule, while trianguable is not. Furthermore, the Oxford English Dictionary contains triangulable and not trianguable. We can thus conclude that triangulable is correct, while trianguable is not.
This seems to be a not uncommon mistake; you can find instances of the incorrect forms stimuable, articuable, and reguable on the web, although they are much less common than the correct form. Possibly people are misled into thinking these are the correct forms by the existence of words like arguable, valuable, and pursuable.

Interesting how litigate ending on late turns into an adjective ending with lable.

@Sebastian: Fixed. Thank you.

Thanks. Interestingly, "inflable" is a Spanish word.

Conversely, "triangulatable" can be found, in obvious analogy to, say, debatable. Maybe you can add that case to your answer.

Yeah, I would have used "triangulatable".  I've never even heard "triangulable".  Though the spell checker claims the first isn't a word.  I claim it's wrong.

In a few less common cases, both the longer and shorter versions can be found in the OED, such as formulatable, manipulatable, ˈregulatable "competing" with formulable, manipulable,  ˈregulable. That does not mean that both forms are of the same frequency or approximate date of entry into the written record. See here and here.

In general, irregular formations tend to be used with more common words. When we apply a transformation with a word we don't use very much, we'll usually use the most straightforward form. So we're less likely to abbreviate "-late" + "-able" to "-lable" if the root is uncommon.

Vox populi, vox deii (From Google Ngrams)


I agree with the outcome but I'm still wondering whether trianguable is really just a typo. You find a few instances of trianguate and trianguation as well, in English and other languages. Again, my spell checker claims it's correct

@AlpinistKitten Disavowed by the OED2.

@AlpinistKitten "Not found" by nGrams does not equal "not a valid word." It's not a dictionary, and it "rounds down" (I find 9 instances) But it does tell you exactly what it purports to, relative frequency of use.

@Greybeard: Is "deii" a typo?

@psmears Oh aye, ’tis that. One would be well counselled to review the divine declensions ere any attempted use thereof.

@psmears No. It's the common dialect of Latin used in Derventio Coritanorum in 78AD. If you've got a problem, take it up with Gnaeus Julius Agricola.

@AlpinistKitten Lowercase l, being one of the smallest letters in the english alphabet, is pretty easy for an OCR system to miss, especially if the document it's run on has been through a few generations of photocopiers. I wouldn't be surprised if the -ua- variants entered the corpus through typos and OCR misreads. Though that's little more than a guess.
